# Moving a sprite with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

this is the code for my Character class:

```
right = [2, 0]

class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Character, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("character_n.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey((25, 25, 25))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

char = Character()

char.rect[0] = 375
char.rect[1] = 400
```

And the code in my game loop that moves the character to the right if the joystick is moved to the right:

```
h_axis_pos = my_joystick.get_axis(0)
v_axis_pos = my_joystick.get_axis(1)

if h_axis_pos >= 0.50:
    if char.rect.right < 800:
       char.rect = char.rect.move(right)
```

This code worked fine when the character was a simple image, but does not work now.

I am confused, since self.rect is initialized and the character is set at the coordinates I selected. I tried to use char.rect[0] in the if and increment it, but still the same error appears:

```
if char.rect.right < 800:
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the same `char`, since it says it is an instance of `pygame.Surface` not `Character`. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: http://dumptext.com/dXBQFTZE

It is very (very!) messy still, but I am sure there's only one char.

Comment: Note that instead of `char.rect = char.rect.move(right)`, you could simply use `char.rect.move_ip(right)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
 if char.rect.right < 800:
      idle = 0
      char.rect = char.rect.move(right)
      char = pygame.image.load("right_n.png")
```

In the line:

```
char = pygame.image.load("right_n.png")
```

You are overwriting your char and assigning a pygame.Surface to it.
So on the next iteration of the game loop it fails.

Comment: Actually, that bit was commented. However, this:


     if idle:
        char = pygame.image.load("character_n.png")


wasn't, and it was causing the problem. Thanks!